# How do you force linq to sql to use the correct data type for sql parameters?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, parameters, types

I have a situation where a certain linq query that runs against a multi-million row table is taking far to long to run. I dissected the linq query output and found that it was creating the parameters for the where clause using the wrong data type. For instance, one field was defined as a Char(12) in the database, but the parameter it was comparing against was declared as NVarChar(12). Once I changed the query to use Char instead of NVarChar, it ran sub-second as it should. Is there a way to get linq to sql to use the correct data type as defined in the .dbml file for that column? I double checked and its defined as DbType="Char(12)" in the data context .dbml file.

Comment: I wonder if you have a bad cached execution plan because nvarchar(12) and char(12) shouldn't make a big difference.  At least I don't think they should.

Comment: After testing quite a bit, it sure did. I cleared the query cache before each run and it went from 4 seconds to 20ms just by changing the data type. I even went as far as converted my linq to sql call to a plain old sql query and used the .ExecuteQuery() method of the data context to run it and it runs lightning fast. Its definitely a data type conversion issue causing SQL to ignore the indexes on the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the command and reset the types of the parameters on it directly (to ansi-string in your case).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype.aspx

Then you might call ExecuteReader on that command, yielding a DbDataReader.  You can hand this DbDataReader to the Translate method of your datacontext, and it will give you the `IEnumerable<T>` that you'd expect from linq.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534213.aspx

---

The performance problem is caused by the query parameter having a different type than the index selected by the query optimizer.  What happens next is that **the entire index is converted into the type of the parameter**.  This is done each time the query is issued - the conversion doesn't hang around for later querying.

I usually see this behavior when sending a collection of strings into the database:

```
  //this query will get correct parameter type
db.Customers.Where(c => c.Name == "Bob")
  //this query can get incorrect parameter type
List<string> names = new List<string>(){"Amy", "Bob"};
db.Customers.Where(c => names.Contains(c.Name));
```